# Allocation mode explanation

Tags: kernel, memory

I have "page allocation failure" reported on my system:

```
[some_app]: page allocation failure: order:4, mode:0x2040d0
```

Could someone please explain what that mode exactly stands for? Am I right that this is for the following GFP flags: `GFP_NOTRACK | GFP_COMP | GFP_WAIT | GFP_IO | GFP_FS` ?

Kernel version is `3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.AV1.x86_64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flags seem to be defined in file `<kernel source directory>/include/linux/gfp.h`, and at least on kernel 4.9.105, mode 0x2040d0 would seem to map to:

`GFP_NOTRACK | GFP_COMP | GFP_FS | GFP_IO | GFP_RECLAIMABLE`

But if I Google for flag definitions, I see in some sources value 0x10 defined as GFP_WAIT instead of GFP_RECLAIMABLE, which seems to match your source.

[This LWN discussion](https://lwn.net/Articles/274971/) might be useful reading, but the best description I can see is in the comments in `include/linux/gfp.h` file.

In general, these mode flags modify the working of the page allocator.

- GFP_NOTRACK: avoids tracking with `kmemcheck`.
- GFP_COMP: address [compound page](https://lwn.net/Articles/619514/) metadata
- GFP_FS: indicates that the allocator can call down the the low-level filesystem to reclaim pages if necessary; if this is cleared, I think would indicate the allocation is for some filesystem code that may be holding locks... which might be important when using a swap file, for example.
- GFP_IO: indicates that the allocator can start physical I/O to reclaim pages to satisfy this request.
- GFP_RECLAIMABLE: "[this] is used for slab allocations that specify SLAB_RECLAIM_ACCOUNT and whose pages can be freed via shrinkers." This flag is apparently used by memory allocations for filesystems. Basically it seems to mean that there is a kernel function (a shrinker) that can be called to free or minimize this allocation if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @telcoM! I've added kernel version to the description.